# Why my Regex expression doesn't work?

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing, console-application

I have this program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Reviews_browser_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(enter good, that u want to find: ");
            string tovar = Console.ReadLine();
            string page = "http://www.ulmart.ru/search?string=&rootCategory=&sort=6";
            page = page.Insert(35, tovar); // inserts good's id into url


            HttpWebRequest site = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(page);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)site.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            String data = read.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(data);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("ulmart.html", data);

            Console.ReadKey();


            Match m;


            string pattern = "<span[^>]*?>[0-9]{4,10}</span>";


            m = Regex.Match(data, pattern);
            while (m.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found an id " + m.Groups[1] + " at string "+ m.Groups[1].Index);
                m = m.NextMatch();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to get all id numbers from the html file. But i don't know, why using this regex it doesn't find anything, while notepad++ finds each id fine.
The example of html string, that should be found, using this regex:

```
<span class="num">3609304</span>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Because you do not have `m.Groups[1]`, it is empty as you do not have any capturing group in your regex. You can use `<span[^>]*?>([0-9]{4,10})</span>` and access the value with `m.Groups[1].Value`. However, you will be safer using an HTML parser relying on XPath to select exact elements you need rather than trying it the hard way with regex. Are you trying to get inner text of all `span` tags with `class="num"`?

Comment: HTML Aglity Pack is much better than Regex in these situations.

Comment: m value is still NULL

Comment: There is no `span` elements with the text you are looking for on that page.

Comment: No, they exist, notepad++ searches them with this regex
The example: `<span class="num">3609304</span>`

Comment: Most probably the problem is the case sensitivity or the quotes, etc. That is why regex should be avoided when scraping HTML pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve the issue is to use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Install  it as a NuGet package, and use the following method:

```
public List<string> HtmlAgilityPackGetNumericSpan4to10(string html)
{
        var vals = new List<string>();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
        Uri uriResult;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) 
                            && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
        { // html is a URL 
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        else
        { // html is a string
            hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            hap.LoadHtml(html);
        }
        var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='num']");
        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                var val = node.InnerText;
                if (val.ToCharArray().All(p => Char.IsDigit(p)) 
                                 && val.Length >= 4 && val.Length <= 10)
                    vals.Add(val);
            }
        }
        return vals;
}
```

With `"//span[@class='num']"` we collect only the `span` tags that have `class` attribute value equal to `num`. With `if (val.ToCharArray().All(p => Char.IsDigit(p)) && val.Length >= 4 && val.Length <= 10)` we check if the inner text is all numeric and its length is from 4 to 10.

Result with just your example string:

[image]

Comment: I have ab error on this: HtmlAgilityPackGetNumericSpan4to10Severity 
Error CS0116 


A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: Use it inside a class.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).